# Retrieving one record from mysql and storing in an array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I just started php two days ago because I need to code in PHP. Please bear with as I am still reading through the manuals. I would like to retrieve one particular column from the mysql and store the string into an array.

```
mySQL col_1 record: 1, 2, 3
Desired array: ['1', '2', '3']

//mySQL connection
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","my_db");

//Sample job_id 
$user_id  = 40398;

$sql_statement = "SELECT col_1 FROM table1 WHERE name = " . $user_id . " LIMIT 1";
$result_set = mysqli_query($connect, $sql_statement);

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result_set);
$terms = explode(',', $row);
print_r $terms;

mysqli_close($connect);
```

I get an error when I try to print to see the array. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: What you getting error? please mention so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose the array in a parenthesis to use PHP print_r function.

Change

```
print_r $terms;
```

to

```
print_r($terms);
```

More info in the [manual.](http://www.php.net/print_r)

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot the ( ).